# Using a ListDictionary Class setting (Settings.settings)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, settings.settings

In my C# program (.net v4, MS Visual C# Express) I am attempting to use a setting of the class ListDictionary.

Here's my test code:

```
// String setting
Properties.Settings.Default.StringTest = "Llama llama LLAMA!";

// ListDictionary setting
ListDictionary ld = new ListDictionary();
ld.Add("key1", "llama");
ld.Add("key2", "alpaca");

Properties.Settings.Default.LDTest = ld;

// Save settings
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

After executing my code, the *user.config* file is written with the string setting, but not with the ListDictionary setting (excerpt):

```
    <setting name="StringTest" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Llama llama LLAMA!</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="LDTest" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value />
    </setting>
```

List Dictionary is listed as being serializable [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but is there some manual work I need to do to get it into a setting file?  Furthermore, is there any way to figure out what classes/types are able to be used as settings and which are not?

Comment: Any chance on resolving this. I attached a screen shot of the exception that is causing the ListDictionary not to serialize.

Comment: I've turn on throwing all exceptions and even tried trapping the error with a try/catch, but I can't get it to throw an error.  Makes sense that that would be the error though.

Comment: Oh, do you have Just My Code Enabled in Debug Settings? You probably need .Net Framework Source Stepping enabled. This exception is handled inside the framework source. I apologize for not thinking of that earlier. You'll only see your uncaught and/or thrown exceptions if you use Just My Code. I added some suggestions to my earlier post also.

Comment: Turning off "Enable Just My Code" did the trick.  I now get an exception on save().  Thanks for working through this w/ me.

Comment: No problems. I was curious about it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Break When Exceptions thrown enabled, as well as .Net Framework Source Stepping if you want see this exception. While I don't think you want to serialize complex datatypes to the Settings.settings file, you could serialize this to a string separated by semicolons and commas if you were really dead set on doing this.

[image: Make sure you have Break When Exceptions thrown enabled]

Comment: Additionally, the settings file is good for simple property settings, but if you are using to store complex values or data then you are better off providing your own method of storing that data.